# Yii2 query records only if the date time field is greater than today

Tags: yii2

I have a mysql table with one of the fields as datetime in the datetime format. I want to change the following query to one that will check the datetime of each record and only return those records that are greater than the current time and date.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => NflLines::find(),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your column with datetime is named `datetime`, you can do it like this:

```
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\db\Expression;

...

$query = NflLines::find()->where(['>', 'datetime', new Expression('NOW()')]);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);
```

Read more about ways of specifying `where` condition [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail) and wrapping with expression [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) in official docs.